# Mockito do not throw exception

Tags: junit, mockito

I have this method my repository method throws RepositoryException and service method throws Service exception i am mocking the repository and throwing repository exception but it is not throw any exception can anybody please explain what is going on here.

```
public class IndActivityTest {
    static BigDecimal offset;
    static SecurityContext userContext;
    SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter();
    SearchFilterToDB filterToDB = new SearchFilterToDB();
    static BigDecimal limit;
    static User user = null;
    @Mock
    static UserRepository repository;
    @Mock
    static SearchRepository searchRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    static SearchApiServiceImpl  searchApiImple;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp(){
        user = new User();
        String scheme="https";
        userContext = new ServiceSecurityContext(user, scheme);
    }
    @Test
    public void getIndActivitiesPositiveResponse() throws RepositoryException,ServiceException{
        List<IndActivityDetailEntity> activityDetailEntities = new ArrayList<>();
        when(searchRepository.getIndActivitiesFromDB(filterToDB,user)).thenReturn(activityDetailEntities);
        Response response = searchApiImple.getIndActivities(filter, userContext);
        assertEquals(response.getStatus(), 200);
    }
    @Test(expected=ServiceException.class)
    public void getIndActivitiesNegetiveResponse() throws RepositoryException,ServiceException{
        when(searchRepository.getIndActivitiesFromDB(filterToDB,user)).thenThrow(new RepositoryException());
        searchApiImple.getIndActivities(filter, userContext);
    }
}

public Response getIndActivities(SearchFilter searchFilter, SecurityContext securityContext)
        throws ServiceException {
    List<Activity> activities = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        logger.info("Entering getActivities");
        List<IndActivityDetailEntity> activityDetailEntities = new ArrayList<>();
        User user = (User) securityContext.getUserPrincipal();
        SearchFilterToDB searchFilterToDB = newFilterToDB(searchFilter, user);
        activityDetailEntities = searchRepository.getIndActivitiesFromDB(searchFilterToDB, user);
        if (!activityDetailEntities.isEmpty())
            activities = SearchUtil.convertIndActivityToIndActivityDTO(activityDetailEntities, searchRepository);
        logger.info(" Exiting getActivities");
    } catch(Exception e){
        handleException(e);
    }
    return Response.status(200).entity(new InlineResponse200().data(activities)).build();
}


private void handleException(Exception e) throws ServiceException{
    logger.error("Service Exception "+e);
    if( e instanceof ServiceException)
        throw (ServiceException)e;
    if( e instanceof RepositoryException ){
        RepositoryException re = (RepositoryException)e;
        throw new ServiceException(re.getErrorCode(),re,re.getMessage());
    }else{
        throw new ServiceException(e.getMessage(), e,ServiceConstant.UNKNOWN);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used this type of code many times but in this code only i am not able to throw any exception.

Comment: Can you post the relevant method in your repository class and where you set up your mocks?

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: Repository i cannot display here

Comment: Can you add the code for Service method as well?

Comment: sorry but service is just  calling repository method and returning the response.

Comment: doesn't it thorw/convert the exception? just add the code for it,so that we can look

Comment: edited my code you can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is at the line `new FilterToDB(searchFilter, user)` in your `getIndActivities()` method of the service, because `searchFilterToDB` objects are different, the method call is NOT actually mocked.

So, to solve the problem, you need to extract `new` `FilterToDB` object creation to a separate class & mock the method call to that class.

Comment: ServiceException is thrown by service method so when repository throw some repository exception service will catch that exception and throw service exception.